# Setting environment variables within python

Tags: python, linux, bash

There are quite a few question for this topic but unfortunatly they didn't solve my problem.

I have a shell script whose purpose is only to set environment variables (let's call it `env.sh`). A second shell script is the main program script that sources `env.sh` and is using variables that are defined there. This works fine when both are bash-scripts.

I have the problem that I try to replace the main shell script with a python program. This python program does also depend on those environment variables that are set by `env.sh`.

What can I do to source `env.sh` within python before starting any routine that use those environmen variables?

- I have to run `bash -c source env.sh` with the module subprocess. But if I understand correctly this does not work, because the variables are set in the child process of the calling python program and are therefore not available in the parent process. Is this correct?
- A similar solution would have been to use `bash -c source env.sh && env` and read the output of `env` in python, iterate over the list and write into `os.environ`. But this approach would write every variable again, even if it was already defined. What if there are a lot of variables?
- The last solution I could think of was to read and parse the `env.sh` file and set the variables I can find. One problem is that some exports in `env.sh` are nested, mening:

  ```
  export SOMETHING=$FOO/Bar
  ```

  This could become complicated to parse correctly.

Is there another way that I haven't found yet or didn't think of?

Comment: "source env.sh within python" - The problem is right here. Why don't you execute the python script when the environment variables are already set?

Comment: I thought this would be kind of a safety measure to not bail out of the program if needed environment variables are not defined. Instead I read them from the file and set them myself before continuing with the program. That's how it was done in the shell script.

Comment: Don't call the python script directly, use a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. https://github.com/mattseymour/python-env
2. https://github.com/rconradharris/envparse

Env variable sourcing is very common, I would not recommend rolling your own.